# CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Broadcast receiver not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

This is my broadcast receiver. I have added all the details that were required but still it is not working

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent; 
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class myBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = 
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if (isConnected)
        Log.i("NET", "Connected" + isConnected);
    else
        Log.i("NET", "Not Connected" + isConnected);
     }
 }
```

and the manifest file as, I have added all the details the were required but still it is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.mybroadcastreceiver">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <receiver android:name=".myBroadCastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"></action>
        </intent-filter>

     </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have worked everything out but this is not working, any idea what can be missing, I have not made a change in `MainActivity.java` , could that be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps targeting Android 7.0 and higher must register the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast using [`Context.registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)). [(source)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_70)

You can't register it in your manifest, because then your app would wake up every time the user's connectivity changes, which is awful for performance and battery life.